# C# String Manipulation - From: Hello.Test.Trash to Hello.Test

Tags: c#, string

I got a String like:

- `"Hello.Test.Trash"`

or `"Hello.Test.Computer.Trash"`

or `"Haha.Yeah.Space.Car.Trash"`

I want to be able, removing the last word "**Trash**", which is always the same including the preceding dot:

```
"Hello.Test"

"Hello.Test.Computer"

"Hello.Yeah.Space.Car"
```

What would be the best/cleanest way to do that?

Comment: Have you bother to look online, its much more rewarding to find answers out for yourself! hint... string Methods EndsWith(string) and Replace(string, string), or Remove(int, int). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wtc81z6.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one occurrence of '.Trash' at the end:

```
string value = "Hello.Test.Trash";
string notrash = value.Replace(".Trash","");
// notrash = "Hello.Test"
```

If '.Trash' can also be in the middle of the string, and you don't want to replace that:

```
string value = "Hello.Trash.Test.Trash";
string notrash = Regex.Replace(value, @"\.Trash$", "");
// notrash = "Hello.Trash.Test"
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove all instances of .Trash(including in middle )

```
var resultString = inputString.Replace(".Trash", String.Empty);
```

If you are 100% sure that last set of chars will be ".Trash" and you want to remove only the last occurrence of it then you can also use

```
var resultString = inputString.SubString(0, inputString.Lenght - 6); //6 is lenght of .Trash
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myString = myString.Substring(0,myString.Length - "Trash".Length)
```

I would be very carefull using replace, as that would replace the trash in this string twice:

I.trash.in.trash

getting you "I.in"

Answer (score 1):

If .Trash only occurs once in your string you have two options:

```
string s = "Hello.Test.Trash";

string s1 = s.Replace(".Trash", string.Empty);

string s2 = s.Remove(s.IndexOf(".Trash"));
```

Comment: If trash is also in the middle both of these will fail.